# Read guarantee in mysql transactions in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, pdo, transactions, locking

Is there a guarantee that in the following Larave code the minus of `$last` and `$first` are the exact count of inserted values ?

```
$this->tempPage->getConnection()->transaction(function() use($insertables, &$importedCount, $userId){

$first = $this->pageModel->getConnection()->getPdo()->lastInsertId();

$this->pageModel->newQuery()->getQuery()->insert($insertables);

$last = $this->pageModel->getConnection()->getPdo()->lastInsertId();

$importedCount = $last - $first;
```

});

In other words is the table locked in MySql transactions whenever a read query is performed ?

Comment: no, because there's no guarantee your auto increment fields are sequential - if you're on a server with replication, auto inc values may be increasing by two, or three, or more

Comment: Thanks, What is your suggestion for counting inserted fields ? and also is the table locked inside a transaction? I mean when I first get last_insert_id inside a transaction and another session inserts a new data, when I get it again are the values same or different ?

Comment: execute a raw query that just calls the `ROW_COUNT()` function, and `last_insert_id()` gives you the last inserted if for the current session, so no, it wont be overwritten by other transactions on other sessions